# Keydown only triggered with corresponding DOM element in focus jQuery

Tags: jquery, keyboard

When I bring up my calculator, I'd like to be able to use the keyboard or mouse, at my option. I thought I had coded for the keyboard. As it so happens, the keyboard keys print nothing to the console unless I first click on the corresponding button on screen (i.e., give it focus). Then, I can mash any key and print only the number in focus as many times as I would like. If I wish to change numbers, I have to give the desired number focus and then the corresponding number on the keyboard will print to the console.

How do I adjust my code such that, after loading the DOM, the keyboard works automatically, no button focus required?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // declare empty infix string
            let infix = "";
            // get input from user on key press (separate function)
            $(function getInput() {
                $('#one').on("keyup", function() {
                        infix += "1";
                        console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#two').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "2";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#three').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "3";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#four').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "4";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#five').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "5";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#six').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "6";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#seven').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "7";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#eight').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "8";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#nine').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "9";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
                $('#zero').on("keyup", function() {
                    infix += "0";
                    console.log(infix);
                });
            }());

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact, that the key-event is propagatet to the window should simplify your problem by a lot.

*Replace the listener-madness by a simple white-list check.*

```js
// $(fn) is equivalent to $(document).ready(fn)
$(function() {
    // declare empty infix string
    let infix = "";
    // get input from user on key press (separate function)
    (function getInput() {
        $(window).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if("1234567890".includes(e.key)) {
                infix += e.key;
                console.log(infix);
            }
        });
    })(); // It's IIFE, not jQuery
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, worked beautifully! Quick follow-on: How did you know about the event being propagated to the window? Generic events are rather mysterious.

Comment: Hi Ryan, event-propagation is one of the key-concepts in JavaScript/DOM, it's something that you learn on the go.